# Usage of gradient in the updation of weight and bias in neural network

Tags: neural-network

Why do we use the gradient of the loss function to update the weight and bias of a neural network?

for example:

```
new_weight = old_weight - learning_rate * gradient
```

In other words how does gradient help us in updating the weight and bias correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gross simplification: the gradient is multidimensional derivate compacted into a "single structure". The derivate tells you, where the is a local change.
The gradient, tells you where there are local changes in all the dimensions you are considering.

Consider the 3-Dimensional case: our world. Image you are climbing a hill. Suppose your sight is limited at 3 meters for your position. Your goal is to reach the top.

You start from a point, and you look around. As you see 3 meters from your position in your direction, you choose to go where you see that the slope is steeper.
The action of looking around is computing the gradient and correcting your speed.

In your equation, remember this is a gross example, you are saying "Uhm, the first time I checked my direction was 124 degrees, now, looking at the gradient my direction should be 10 degrees. Which direction should I take now".

The `learning rate` or your equation is a coefficient that you can interpret as "friction", or "trust": you don't want to change your direction of 114 degres in one shot, instead you want to change with respect to the magnitude of the new measure.
You detect that the new direction should be 114 degrees (124-10) less the current one. So, if your learning rate is low, your new direction will impact less than in the case when the learning rate is higher.

This example gets generalized on multiple dimensions.